# passing data in the current page of a p-table column to another application

Tags: angular, primeng-datatable

I have a p-table which has pagination, filters , and sorting enabled. on click of a button, the data in a particular column of the current page of the p-table should be exported to another application. 
with the below steps , i am able to export all the ids in ticketids array, however , i need to send only ids in the current page.

in the below code, data represents the p-table data in all the pages.
 let jsonData = data.filteredValue ? JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data.filteredValue)) : JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data.value));

```
let ticketIds = [];
for(let objTicket of jsonDrilldownData){
    ticketIds.push(objTicket["id"]);
}
```

How can i do get only the current page ids. can anyone please provide suggestions.

Comment: what do you mean by another application? is it a different domain?

Comment: never mind that part, i am able to already do that. Now i want to just send a much smaller subset of data that represents the current page of the p-table.

Comment: what primeng version are you using?